# Calculate in C#

Tags: c#

Hello everyone I am trying to make since of what I am doing wrong or maybe I am over thinking it again. I am trying to create a class and in the class I am calling 2 private variables such as num1 and num2. Then i create a public property that corresponds to num 1 and num2. Then after I create that I need to create a public overriable method called calculate and this will add the two variables together and returns the results. Then I have a add button that I have to  add the code to the button that adds the two numbers and output the result to a messagebox.I have tried a couple different ways and I still am not getting it.
Here is code 1:

```
 public abstract class CalulateValues
{
    protected List<int> values = new List<int>();
    public void AddValue(int value) { values.Add(value); }
    public abstract int Calculate();

}

public class Add : CalulateValues
{
    public override int Calculate()
    {
        return values.Sum(x => x);
    }
}
```

and here is code 2 I tried:

```
class CalculateValues
{
    private int _num1;
    private int _num2;


    public int Num1
    {
        get
        {
            return _num1;
        }
        set
        {
            _num1 = value;
        }
    }
    public int Num2
    {
        get
        {
            return _num2;
        }
        set
        {
            _num2 = value;
        }
    }
    public virtual int calculate()
    {
        return _num1 + _num2;

    }
}
```

Now when it comes with the button I have tried this code:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        CalculateValues myAdd = new CalculateValues();
        MulitplyValues Add = new MulitplyValues();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int total = myAdd.Add(int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox2.Text));    
        MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());

    }
```

I am not too sure what I am doing wrong maybe I am not laying out the code the right way.

Comment: Firstly, I'd suggest fixing your naming. Having one class called `CalulateValues` and another called `CalculateValues` is *very* confusing, as is having a variable called `Add` which is an instance of `MulitplyValues`.

Comment: It looks to me like you are not calling Calculate() anywhere

Comment: /Thread .... Link to the [Best Page Ever](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/unmainnaming.html)

Comment: Maybe I am just getting myself more confused then I need to be. Now the private can be like this right 'private int num1; private int num2;' the to create a public properties you can go like this 'public int Add(); num1 = num1; num2 =num2; return num1 + num2;' or am I just getting it all confused.

Comment: Ask yourself when you think about naming variables, does that make sense: "MulitplyValues Add = new MulitplyValues();". Also consider that all locally defined variables are gone when you leave the method/Constructor. You are quite confused.

Comment: You seriously should read a C# book or at least C# tutorial which also explains you OOP concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared `myAdd` as a local variable in the Form2 constructor. Declare it as a global variable in order to be able to call it from `button1_Click()`

In addition to this, are you getting any error or exception? Second, where did you declare Add method that accepts two parameters?

Comment: I think you mean add it as a field of Form2, not a global variable.

Comment: @DavidKemp it will be global in the context of Form2 class, but yes, it should be declared as a field in Form2 in order to be accessible to other methods and properties of Form2 class. (I believe we were on the same track :-) )

Comment: Global Context has a special meaning, which is invalid in C# as you can't have global variables - you'd have to use (public) static members. But yes, we were both on the same track.

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    CalculateValues myAdd;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myAdd = new CalculateValues();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int total = myAdd.Add(int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox2.Text));    
        MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());
    }
}
```

And then go and look up firstly a C# tutorial, then look at detail on variable scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
int total = myAdd.Add(int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox2.Text));
```

myAdd has no Add method at all. It is `AddValue`. And you should call `Calculate` and retrieve the result.

Declare myAdd as member variable instead local in constructor.

And try that:

```
myAdd.AddValue(int.Parse(textBox1.Text)
myAdd.AddValue(int.Parse(textBox2.Text);    
int total = myAdd.Calculate();
MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());
```

Multiple bugs in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a method Add, you shoudl use the method calculate like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int total = myAdd.Add(int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox2.Text));    
    MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare the `myAdd` variable outside of the constructor, even if you only initialize in the Form2() constructor.

Your `CalculateValues` class does not have an "`Add`" method.
Instead you should be calling the "`Calculate`" method like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        CalculateValues myAdd = new CalculateValues();
        MulitplyValues Add = new MulitplyValues();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int total = myAdd.Calculate(int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox2.Text));    
        MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());

    }
```